# Getting variable out of a get ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

This problem is actually caused by my not fully understanding jquery.

I have some code that i tried to put in a function to use multiple times.

```
function actors(query){
    $.get("websit.com?title=" + query + "&type=json", function(html){
        var result = html;
        var obj = eval ("(" + result + ")");
        var actor = obj[0].actors;
        return actor; //as far as im aware this does nothing
    });
    return 0; // gets here and returns zero, returning actor here returns undefined
}
```

The actor variable holds the information i need, however I'm struggling to get the variable out of the function.
Because of the inner function it will run through and get to the `return 0;`

If i try assign a variable to the inner function it will return an object and not the return variable.

Any solutions or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is asked 1000 times monthly. You can not make an asynchronous call act like a synchronous call. That is what the callbacks are for.

You are also using jQuery, there is no need to use eval! Set the right content type and it will parse the data for you.

Basic idea with a callback

```
function actors(query, callback){
    $.getJSON("websit.com?title=" + query + "&type=json", function(data) {
        var actor = data[0].actors;
        callback(actor);
    });
}


function processResults(info){
    console.log(info);
}

actors("Something", processResults);
```

Comment: So I write the continuation of the scripts execution in process results?
The initial script will end, and the the callback will receive the results and execute.

Comment: Yes your logic would be in two steps. First step is to gather the information and make the call, second step [the callback] will handle the results.

Comment: Makes sense, what happens if you want to run the function more than one time, and compare results?

Comment: Used a global counter and global variables and can get it to work perfectly, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

While it's true you can't do just that, I've found that something like this is an acceptable work-around in most cases that I've run in to:

```
function getMeSomeJSON(query) {    
  return $.get("websit.com?title=" + query + "&type=json");
}
```

Which will return the request's response to whatever calls it.

Alternately, you can:

- Pass the response to a callback.
- Use $.ajax with async: false, however, this is considered bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

[Read the documentation.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) It has some examples, including data type handling. And a simple check should help to determine what to return.

Answer (score 0):

As you have noticed yourself, your ajax response handler executes *after* the actors function has returned, thus making it rather difficult to return a value. The standard solution would be to return a promise from the actors function. You can read up on promises, or deferred objects, in [jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

This would be my suggestion:

```
function actors(query){
    var actorsPromise = $.Deferred();
    $.get("websit.com?title=" + query + "&type=json", function(html){
        var result = html;
        var obj = eval ("(" + result + ")");
        var actor = obj[0].actors;
        actorsPromise.resolve(actor);
    });
    return actorsPromise;
}

actors(/* your query */).done(function(actor) {
    //do whatever you need with your actor
});
```